# Rails filter by associations attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model 'Client' and 'Course', they association as many to many by 'cient_courses' table, Course can published to Client which created a ClientCourse record. one course can't published to one client multiple times. now I want to find all Client record that one specific course(let's course1) can published on to, which is all Client record that have no association with B or have association with B but not with course1, is there any easy way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a work solution, easy to understand:

```
`client_ids = Client.all.pluck(:id) - course.clients.pluck(:id)`

`Client.find(client_ids)`
```